# Wrong event.target on jQuery live click event

Tags: jquery

When i use the following to register a handler for click events:

```
$('.drilldown-action > li').live('click', function(event){
    drilldown.loadActions($(event.target));
});
```

With HTML:

```
<ul class="drilldown-action">
    <li data-action="Dummy"><a href="#">Dummy</a> Dum</li>
</ul>
```

In the browser ( using Chrome ) I click on the `a` tag, how can i get the jQuery object that the event was registered on? I expect the `li` element to be the event target, as that is what i put in the selector. I know i can just use `.parent()` for this case, but is there a way to get the object that matched the selector, instead of the bottom event target? Also using `.parent()` is a pain because when the other part of the `li` is clicked, i wouldn't have to need to use it.

Comment: Are you aware that `.live()` is deprecated? You should be using `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was deprecated already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`e.target` is the link tag.

You should use `this` to get `li` tag that is the element bound to the handler.

**Code:**

```
$('.drilldown-action > li').live('click', function(event){
    drilldown.loadActions($(this));
});
```

**Note:** As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `this` just like you would with any other event.

```
drilldown.loadActions($(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would make sure I always pass what I want:

```
$('.drilldown-action > li').live('click', function(event){
    drilldown.loadActions($(event.target).closest('li'));
});
```

According to jQuery api documentation, *closest()* will always pass the "li" element:

> **Description:** For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.
>   https://api.jquery.com/closest/